# ForEach not working in SwiftUI after conforming to Identifiable protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have an array of `Message` which conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol but I keep getting this error: `Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred`. Even with the `id: \.self` won't work.

What's going on here?

```
struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var createdAt: Date = Date()
    var senderId: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.senderId = dictionary["senderId"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

@State var messages: [Message] = []

ForEach(messages) { message in
    // Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred
}
```

Comment: `ForEach ` cannot be empty and must be with a view.

Comment: I've put your ForEach into List and all compiled well. Tested with Xcode 11.2. The compiler might give wrong place and/or error in SwiftUI, so you need to provide complete code snapshot of view body where do you see this error. I suppose that the reason is in different place.

Answer (score -1):

You need `Text(message.id.uuidString)`

```
import SwiftUI

struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var createdAt: Date = Date()
    var senderId: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.senderId = dictionary["senderId"] as? String ?? ""

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var messages: [Message] = [Message.init(dictionary: ["text":"t1","senderId":"1"]),Message.init(dictionary: ["text":"t2","senderId":"2"])]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(messages) { message in
                Text(message.id.uuidString)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Message: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var createdAt: Date = Date()
    var senderId: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.senderId = dictionary["senderId"] as? String ?? ""

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var messages: [Message] = []

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(messages) { message in
                Text(message.id.uuidString)
            }
        }.onAppear() { 
            self.messages  = [Message.init(dictionary: ["text":"t1","senderId":"1"]),Message.init(dictionary: ["text":"t2","senderId":"2"])]
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I get `Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred`

Comment: my array is filled later with data at the beginning its empty. So it's filled on `.onAppear` can you try with an empty array and then fill it on appear ?